# Where can I find a good overview of the Scala type system?

Tags: scala, types

Where can I find a comprehensive overview of Scala's type system (existential types, type bounds, view bounds, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), Chapter 3 (Types).

Answer (score 1):

Programming in Scala, Second Edition, by Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon, Bill Venners.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the diagram here (it's a bit small but spot on): http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/scalas-hierarchy.html

You can also read this chapter which talks in depth about types: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html and http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html#sec:view-bounds

Comment: Same diagram can be found inside Programming in Scala

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for the class hierarchy - I'm looking for a catalog of the different kind of typing Scala supports.

Comment: @idonnie +1 I own that book and it's the best

Comment: @cyber-monk +1 for those links, also I could suggest Scala Language Specification http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf, but I haven't read it completely, yet